# How to run MPI on multiple host

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I'm trying to run my openmpi project on 2 hosts. If I run it on my machine with

`mpirun -np 2 ./test`

It works, but when I run the command

`mpirun -host hostaname1,hostname2 -np 2 ./test`

It doesn't work. It looks like it might be deadlocked, but the shell doesn't give me any error. The 2 hosts are located in the same LAN connected by an ethernet cable. Both OSes are Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64. One runs on a bootable USB and one directly on the hard disk. The executable is located on both machines.

Comment: Run with `--verbose`.  Either you dont have passwordless (via ssh key) login setup or firewall is blocking requests.

Comment: still no informations from the shell

Comment: Getting exactly the same error. --verbose is also not showing up anything. Any luck on this anyone?